# Google map not displaying in "row" class

Tags: html, css, google-maps, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to display google maps and every time I use this

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

The map is showing.It is working as it should.

but when I put this div in a "row" class

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns" id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

the map disappears.

This is the css

```
html{
height: 100%;
  }

body{
height: 100%;
 }

#map-canvas{
height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This is because you're setting a height on the body and html, then on the map-canvas id. However, the row has no height. This means the map-canvas, will only have 100% height of it's container (the row)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I set the row height to 100% and it worked. Does that mean I've to set the height 100% for every div level above map-canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height:100%` will only work if parent's height is explicitly defined or if all the parents have height 100% till html tag.